# django admin working only debug true mode?

Tags: python, django

I have problem with `DEBUG` mode. If I set the `DEBUG=True`,Then my django admin dashboard working perfectly. But when I changed the `DEBUG=False`,Then it gives the following error,

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

**Note:** I am currently running my app in dev mode. But I don't need to run my app in `DEBUG=True` mode.

Comment: Does your command prompt contain any error information?

Comment: Thanks for reply @kroolik. Yes, I have error in my prompt. I have solved the error, But it didn't serve the static files

Comment: ```python manage.py collectstatic``` In debug mode django gets static files from applications. You have to collect them to serve from static root. Also don't forget to add static url patterns to urls.py

Comment: Thanks for reply @username. I have tried as you said, But it gives the error **OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'**. I have tried with chmod,But no luck.

Comment: define STATIC_ROOT as an absolute path at settings.py. What i understand from your comment is that you have defined it as a relative path and Django is trying to write under root directory.

Comment: Thanks @username. You have solved my problem. sorry for late response.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be `ALLOWED_HOSTS`? This trips up lots of people when they finally deploy and turn off `DEBUG` for the first time. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts